# Sql query error in java program

Tags: java, sql

I have developed a java program and I need to update and insert the login details of users.  I have two textfields created and two buttons name add user and edit the user. when I type the username and password in the two textfields the user added to the database successfully, the error is in the edit user, I want to update the password of the user based on username, 
I'm getting SQL error when trying to update the user,

here is my SQL query for updating the password of a user based on his username,

```
String sql = "UPDATE Admin SET password='"+JT_pass1.getText()+"' WHERE
username = "+JT_username1.getText();
```

when i execute im getting this error,

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 
'sss' in 'where clause'
```

"sss"  is what I entered to username field,
Mysql database I have admin table which consists of two columns admin and username,

I cannot figure out where am I getting wrong, please any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You are missing quotes around `JT_username1.getText()`. Better: use placeholders.

Comment: you forgot single quote `...WHERE username = '"+JT_username1.getText()+"'" ;`

Comment: Try using prepared statement.

Comment: Little Bobby Tables, we call him. https://xkcd.com/327/ - yes, use prepared statements. Never ever copy data that some evil mind entered on your text field to your SQL. Never ever.

Comment: sir,thank you for you help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get this to work, you need to add quotes around the username like so:

```
  String sql = "UPDATE Admin SET password='"+JT_pass1.getText()+"' WHERE
username = '"+JT_username1.getText()+"'";
```

However, updating the database this way is vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), so it would be much better to use [Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).

Answer (score 4):

Your immediate problem is that you forgot to place single quotes around the username in your query.  Hence, the database is interpreting `sss` as a column.  But you should really be using prepared statements:

```
String query = "UPDATE Admin SET password=? WHERE username = ?";
PreparedStatement update = con.prepareStatement(query);
update.setString(JT_pass1.getText());
update.setString(JT_username1.getText());
update.executeUpdate();
```

There are many advantages to using prepared statements.  First, it will automatically take care of proper escaping of strings and other types of data.  In addition, it will prevent SQL injection from happening.

Answer (score 1):

To consider "JT_username1.getText()" as a part of you query string, you have to enclose it under proper quotation.
Same like added "JT_pass1.getText()" between single and double quote, you have to add "JT_username1.getText()" as well.

```
String sql = "UPDATE Admin SET password='" + JT_pass1.getText() + "' WHERE username = '"+JT_username1.getText()+"'";
```